# Shortcut for switching between edit windows in Delphi IDE?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

Is there a shortcut to switch between two edit windows in the Delphi IDE?

Delphi XE here.

Comment: I assume you mean edit window as in what you get when you do "New edit window" from the editor context menu. I can't find any shortcut.

Comment: @David: exactly. I want a split-screen setup and would like to be able to switch between the two edit windows using the keyboard.

Comment: It's not even in the ALT+TAB list.....

Comment: You can use alt+end to go the the "next" window.

Comment: It used to be Alt+End on the older products when you used the multi-window UI, but that swapped between all the windows, not just the editor ones.

Comment: Thanks! Is there also a shortcut for the previous window? That would satisfy me even if it forces me to keep some internal state :)

Comment: I tend to use the F6 key and type in a part of the unit name, as this can be done without much fuss, and since I have 100 units open sometimes, Alt-End would take me forever.

Comment: @WarrenP: the idea is not to switch between units in one edit window, but to have two edit windows (split screen) and being able to quickly switch forth and back.

Comment: I have a vague recollection of a shortcut Alt+0 (zero) but have no Delphi around to check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Alt+End to go the the next window. I don not know of a way to go to the previous window. You could of course use the windows menu.

Using Alt+W will show the menu and then you can use the shortcuts for the units to select a window.

[image]

Comment: Can you get this to work? Alt+End does nothing for me. I can only make it fly by using menu accelerators: Alt, W, X. What's more the list of editor windows is incomplete. It is missing the editor window bound inside the main IDE window. I'm on XE2, FWIW.

Comment: `Alt + End` works for me. I use a classic undocked layout for the split screen desktop and no other windows so in this case it works nicely. Going through the menu takes longer than using the mouse IMHO.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I have tested in both XE and XE2 and it works. I use docked mode and I am only able to switch between the "editing windows", there is no way back to the main IDE.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done with the usual keyboard combination for switching tabbed views in most Windows applications:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> = Switch to next open code window

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> = Switch to previous open code window

Comment: Why the downvote? That's how it works in my (docked) IDE... If an editor window has focus, Ctrl+Tab switches to the next opened source tab, and Shift+Ctrl+Tab to the previous one...

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you're talking about switching between a form and its supporting code, the `[F12]` key will toggle back and forth between the two.